# WPF Binding : accessing subproperties of bound object

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a control with a property named `Item` of type `X`, 
`Item` has a property named `Tag` of type `Y`, and `Tag` has some other properties (`caption`, `location`,...).

I've written a control template for my control, and I need to access the `Tag`'s properties (`caption`, `location`,...etc) so I've used Binding with `RelativeSource` `TemplatedParent`, and as a `Path`  I've tried to use `Path=Item.Tag.caption` as follows :

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="y:myControl">
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
           <SolidColorBrush 
                Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                Path=Item.Tag.caption}" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But I am getting the following error : 
`Tag` property not found for '`object`' because `data item is null` and I am getting no results.

Comment: Are you sure you have valid value in Item property? How and when do  you set it? source code of Item property would help.

Comment: Yes, please post your code for the control.

Comment: Actually I am using yfiles library for wpf, and the control is the [EdgeSegmentControl](http://docs.yworks.com/yfileswpf/html/AllMembers_T_yWorks_yFiles_UI_Drawing_EdgeSegmentControl.htm), the `Tag` property is part of an `IEdge` interface, so I guess I need to access `Item` as an `IEdge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to perform a cast in the `Path` variable before accessing the properties as follows : `Path=Item.(myNameSpace:X.Tag).(myNameSpace:Y.caption)`
For more information check [WPF Binding : Casting in binding path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560550/wpf-binding-casting-in-binding-path)